# Swift dyld: Symbol not found error after updating to Swift 4 on iOS 8.3

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, swift4

After updating my code to Swift 4 my app is crashing on **iOS 8.3** with the following error:

> dyld: Symbol not found: _NSCharacterEncodingDocumentOption
> Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/213D60CD-1ED9-4811-A3C7-B47383557453/development.app/development
> Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit

```
  var decoded: String {
    
    let encodedData = self.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
    let attributedOptions: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey : Any] = [
           .documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
           .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue
    ]
    
    do {
         let attributedString = try NSAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: attributedOptions, documentAttributes: nil)
         return attributedString.string
    } catch _ {
        return self   
    } 
}
```

Comment: `NSCharacterEncodingDocumentOption` is a global variable which is [marked as **iOS11+**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nscharacterencodingdocumentoption?language=objc). Does any part of your code have references to `NSCharacterEncodingDocumentOption` or `NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.characterEncoding`? As far as I experienced with other constants, this sort of runtime crashes happens, even if the part is contained in a `#if available` block.

Comment: yes I am using that.

Comment: I have added the code. do you thing this might be the issue and what is the solution.

Comment: It may be. Try using `NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey("CharacterEncoding")` instead of `.characterEncoding` and see what happens in iOS 8.x.

Comment: @OOPer working good now. Thank you